# Javascript closure inside for loops

Tags: javascript, browser

I am in the process of learning JavaScript. While I completely understand that JavaScript does only have function scope and not block scope, I have stumbled accross an example of a for loop in which functions are created completely and I completely ignore why the following example does not work like one would expect it to.

```js
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = function() {          // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
  };
}
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                      // and now let's run each one to see
}
```

It outputs this:

> My value: 3
>   My value: 3
>   My value: 3

And not:

> My value: 0
>   My value: 1
>   My value: 2

Now I know that the solution would be something like this would be to create a function that returns a function returning the i value which would create a closure for said function.

However, my question is rather, and I have seen a couple of explanations which I don't quite get, why the example does not work in the first place and what is actually happening?

I am unsure how the array func is filled with three keys:

func[0], func[1] and func[2] while the function declaration will always return 3? Why would func[0] even exist in the first place and not only func[3]? It seems to me that there some kind of scope is created in the for loop but only for assigning a key but not for the assignment which I find odd.

Could someone enlighten me? How would a step by step evaluation of the for-loop look like and why?

Thank you very much for your help already!

Comment: The value of `i` in the function is referencing the value of `i` outside, which keeps changing.  So when you finally all `func[x]`, the value of `i` is 3 (which broke the `for` loop at `i < 3`), which is shown to you.

Comment: Also note that in ES2015 via `let` and `const` declarations JavaScript *does* have block scope.

Comment: *While I completely understand that JavaScript does only have function scope and not block scope* You completely understand incorrectly.

Comment: @torazaburo: I am a newcomer to programming, so sorry if I got that wrong. Could you maybe elaborate or provide a link to help explain, please?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Thank you! This is I guess a side effect of close which wasn't wanted here.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: This is somehow confusing as well, though, because this means JavaScript passes i as call by reference here, right? I thought JavaScript was call by value in all cases but arrays and objects?

Answer (score -1):

> func[0], func[1] and func[2] while the function declaration will always return 2?

No. `func[i]` always returns `3`, because `i` is `3` when the function runs.

> It seems to me that there some kind of scope is created in the for loop

There isn't (well, there is, but `let` isn't in play so it isn't used for anything). The scope is defined by the enclosing function. `i` exists in *that* scope and gets changed by the for loop.

---

> How would a step by step evaluation of the for-loop look like and why?

```
var funcs = [];
```

Create an array

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
```

Sets i to 0, 1, 2, 3.

```
  funcs[i] = function() {          // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
  };
```

Assigns a function to the array at whatever `i` is currently

```
}
```

End of loop

```
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
```

Sets j to 0, 1, 2, 3.

i is still 3.

```
  funcs[j]();                      // and now let's run each one to see
```

Calls the first function. `i` is `3`.
Calls the second function. `i` is `3`.
Calls the third function. `i` is `3`.

```
}
```

Fin.

Comment: This is somehow confusing as well, though, because this means JavaScript passes i as call by reference here, right? I thought JavaScript was call by value in all cases but arrays and objects?

Comment: @Sebastian — It doesn't pass any variable. Your code never passes any argument at all when you call a function.